# Change which keys or characters trigger vscode autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode, love it so far, but I am having a problem changing the intellisense autocompletion trigger. In a javascript file, typing `.` (period, dot) or `(` (parenthesis) autocompletes the suggestion. I find this extremely annoying.

I would like to make autocomplete trigger only on tab.

I've read this page:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

I've searched my keybindings.json file and couldn't find a `.` or `(` keybinding so I could turn this off.

Any help is appreciated and sorry if I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Have you tried anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

copy and paste the following code in `settings.json`, `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false`