# How prevent VS Code from accepting a 'suggestion' when typing a period?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code is inserting a suggestion when typing, and I don't want it to insert the suggestion unless I hit either 'Tab' or 'Enter'.

I want to be able to write `cy.get('.my-selector').click()` but instead VS Code auto completes to `crypto.get`

I'm writing a Cypress test, so I type `cy` - Then the suggestion box pops up, and the first option is `crypto` (not what I want). I type a period '.' so I can call a function on this `cy` object, but VS Code instead accepts the first suggestion, which is `crypto`. Now I have to delete this and try again.

I have looked through the VS Code settings for `suggestions`. I have looked at the keybindings for `acceptSelectedSuggestion` and `suggest`. I have disabled ALL extensions.

[This is a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436446/visual-studio-code-intellisense-auto-complete-behaviour#37456838), but I actually want the opposite.

This is a javascript file. On Mac.

VS Code info:
Version: 1.42.1
Commit: c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054
Date: 2020-02-11T14:44:27.652Z
Electron: 6.1.6
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0

Comment: are you talking about disabling intellisense ?

Comment: Hit the ESC key.

Comment: I like IntelliSense, but in this case it is very unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks for `ESC` option. That adds a keystroke though. I'd love to only accept an IntelliSense suggestion when I hit `Enter` or `TAB`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change trigger keys on vscode autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366204/change-trigger-keys-on-vscode-autocomplete)

Comment: Yes, thanks @Tedskovsky!!!!

Comment: I even looked several times at that setting but didn't realize that it was important since the description just mentioned semicolon!